# Intergrate camera without deprecated methods and backwards support

Tags: android, android-camera, deprecated, android-5.0-lollipop

I want to build an application where the front camera of the device is used to project the current image to a `SurfaceView`. All the tutorials I found so far implement this by using a `Camera` object from the android.hardware package.

This method, however, seems to be deprecated. When trying the 'new' preferred way to implement this feature following the [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/package-summary.html), I get the warning it can only be used with API level 21, which is pretty useless.

So I would like to know  the currently preferred way to implement camera functionality in an application. Or is there maybe some support library for API levels lower than 21?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Deprecated interface does not mean you should not use it.  It means you should know that it will be phasing out in the future.

As a general rule, it is better to use a newer interface if possible, in order to avoid the need to update the software later.

The fact that API level 21 does not yet have a large enough market share means that you are probably better off using the old interface for now, and keep in mind that in a year or two, you may need to update the implementation.

Comment: Is there not a backwards support library? Like with for example the `ActionBar`

Comment: It doesn't look like it, but I was trying to make a more general point.  Usually when a new interface is created that requires a new OS version, you don't get this luxury.  But I wouldn't worry about it too much.  I'm guessing there'll be applications using the old interface for a long while.

Comment: Not exactly the answer I was hoping for, but I guess there is no other way than. Thanks anyway. When no other answers arrive with a better solution, I will accept the answer.

Answer (score 4):

I think you can implement the camera function in both sets of API and check the device`s build version first then decided to call which one implementation.

eg:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
      openCameraNewAPI();
}else{
      openCameraOldAPI();
}
```

Comment: Is the new camera the exact same except it references the camera2 class?

Comment: can you place of these methods